# Macros constantly resulting in 'invalid name'

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I'm a newcomer to Stata after using R for a long time.

I'm trying to perform any action which involves a macro, such as a loop and it is constantly giving me an `invalid name r(198)` error.

For example, when I first start up Stata, I enter the following code into the command prompt:

```
local hello 123
di 'hello'
```

This results in:

```
'hello' invalid name    
r(198);
```

Similarly, I try:

```
forvalues i=1/5 {
    display 'i'
}
```

Which results in the same `invalid name` error.

I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong. I have tried putting the same commands into a `do` file and running them, but the same thing occurred.

I was wondering if it's something to do with how I'm running the code [as this link alludes to](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-02/msg00897.html), but nothing suggested there worked for me.

I'm running Stata remotely from a server, if that could affect anything.

Comment: Enclose your macros between `" "`.

Comment: And it seems you are not referencing your macros correctly. It should be something like ``display "`i'"``.

Comment: I can't believe I've been caught up on something as trivial as using ' instead of `. How embarassing.. thanks for pointing that out. It works fine now.

Comment: But note that is not the only problem. `display` expects a string or a scalar. Strings are to be put between quotes. So two problems there.

Comment: Only somewhat pedantically, I think technically it is "dereferencing" rather than "referencing".

Comment: Confusion on this score can often be traced to learners not starting at the source, i.e. http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u.pdf At 18.3.1 in which local macros are introduced the use of different quotation marks is explained. (Different marks are needed if only because local macro references can be nested; otherwise `'a'b'c'` would be hopelessly ambiguous.)

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I'd say a Stata programmer refers to macros and Stata (tries to) interpret those references. I don't think discussions of pointers, addresses etc. are exactly analogous to how Stata macros are interpreted.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer Not quite. Quotation marks are not needed to `display` local macros that contain numeric characters.

Comment: Also, `display %4.3f _pi` and `display ln(1000)` illustrate many numeric uses of `display`with no uses of scalars, macros or strings.

Comment: @Nick and Dimitriy, thank you both for your comments.